# Jmeter is not handling huge JSON payload

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm trying to execute the Jmeter script POST call with some 55 thousands of line JSON payload, with this request I see the error as 500 in the Jmeter tool and also seen JSON parser error in the log-entries.

I think Jmeter is not handing with these huge request payload and not parse the correct JSON data to server.

**NOTE: With the same payload I am able to execute the API via POSTMAN**.

Please suggest how to handle huge payload in the Jmeter.

Thanks,

Comment: Try it using just a single line as a test. The 500 is always a null pointer issue, at least everything that I have ever seen with 500 is something the code expects but does not exist. If you still get the 500 then debug on the server side to see what is expected and determine what is not being passed.

Comment: Thanks Elijah,
I got this server error- JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 682072
But my payload is valid one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a copy-paste issue, I would recommend using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) directly in the HTTP Request sampler body like:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.json,,)}
```

[image]

A better idea would be going for [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it/) sampler which has [nice feature of streaming the file directly to the server](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html) without loading it in memory first

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, problem is resolved now able to parse the JSON from a file